# Pandas: how to have preview of several rows sorted under certain columns

Tags: pandas

If i have a Data Frame(df) as :

```
Year Rate
2001 10
2001 3 
2001 5
2001 3
2001 6
2002 2
2002 7
2002 4
2002 9
2002 8
...  ...
2018 8
2018 6
2018 4
2018 6
2018 5
```

How do i get a Data Frame that show only first 2 rows of each years, like:

```
Year Rate
2001 10
2001 3 
2002 2
2002 7
...  ...
2018 8
2018 6
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('Year').head(2)
print (df1)
    Year  Rate
0   2001    10
1   2001     3
5   2002     2
6   2002     7
10  2018     8
11  2018     6
```